# Video playback in games - formats & decoding

Tags: video

What free / non-restrictive open-source solutions (not GPL) are available for decoding game videos?

The requirements are simple:

- a relatively easy to use C API
- encoded files must be quite small
- there must be an application that converts videos from any format (whatever codec is installed on Windows or equivalent amount of internally decoded formats)
- decoding has to happen fairly quickly
- bonus points go to file formats that are popular / actively supported and
  developed

Comment: Should it work on Windows, Windows Phone, Mac, Linux, Android, iPhone/iPad or something else?

Comment: @RoyT. It's just decoding, so there shouldn't be any problems with platforms. But the main platform I currently work on is Windows (XP/Vista/7), if that's what you wanted to know.

Comment: Ah yes I indeed meant to ask on what platforms the movie should be viewable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org)** lets you decode all kinds of audio and video data thanks to libavcodec. Most of it is licensed under the LGPL, which allows commercial use, [but some parts are under GPL, and some parts might infringe patents](http://www.ffmpeg.org/legal.html).

You might be able to avoid legal problems by using the free **Ogg format** (maintained by the [Xiph.org](http://xiph.org/) foundation), probably with [Vorbis](http://www.vorbis.com/)+[Theora](http://www.theora.org/) for lossy compression. FFmpeg offers support for decoding those through libvorbis and libtheora, and will let you convert from any other format through the `ffmpeg` command-line tool.

Comment: I apologize for taking so long to accept the answer, I had to write a test app to learn more about how the system works and get basic video playback running on screen. If anyone's interested (it's very basic and doesn't cover a lot of things, including frame rates, seeking and error handling), it can be downloaded here: https://www.box.com/s/0qhpzsmhknjqewffoevm